# Best way to implement Register in a Java Website

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, web

I have started working on a Web java learning project.

I am making a webapp and I want to register users to the website:

Whats the best way to implement registration functionality:

- Have a register.html and in form call a servlet register which registers the user into database.
- Or have a jsp page which does all this or similarly call the servlet .
- Or any other..

Please explain the reasons too, that why one is better than other, or why some method should be used or preferred?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three that you cite are equivalent.  JSPs are compiled into servlets that are HTML factories.

Yes, you need a web UI.

You'll need a database to persist the data, so you'll be using JDBC.

You'll need some object and relational models representing users and their credentials.

You'll want to read about Model-2 MVC for web apps.  It describes an architecture where JSPs interact with a servlet, which delegates to other objects to do the work and redirects the response to the right JSP depending on what happens.

You'll want to read about the front controller servlet.

Answer (score 0):

I will go for option 1 :

> "Have a register.html and in form call a servlet register which
>   registers the user into database."

but with a sort of javascript/jquery validations.

Create a html page which contains form and js to validate form fields and a servlet to make 
database entries for newly registered user. Options 2 is also similar with this.

Answer (score 0):

Both the methods mentioned by you are same. Take html page and then call a servlet to persist in database or you take JSP page to do,both are same,as in both you are using servlets.. In both methods you will use server side validation and also handle for SQL injection.

If you are comfortable with any of the MVC framework then try to use it.